# Neo4j - Export all paths to csv. One row per path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, export-to-csv, graph-databases

I have problem with exporting to CSV.
So - i have graph as follows:

---

### [image: Example graph]

And i need to export it to CSV, where one path, is in one row. So the output will be:
[image]

---

And i have no clue how the Cypher query should work like, to export it to CSV using apoc.* procedures.
**Important note**: "1", "2", etc, are one of the properties from node(and i need to only export this one property value).
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without to know the length of the longuest path ...

When you have your path, you can use the `extract` function to create an array of id : `extract(x IN NODES(path) | x.id) AS myIds`.

Then with the `apoc.export.csv.query` you can export your query as a CSV, but the result will be :

```
myIds
1|2|3
A|B|C
```

NB: Per default the `|` is the array separator.